# Output of process in Java is different from normal command

Tags: java, ubuntu, freerdp

I am trying to write code which runs xfreerdp. When I write like this:

```
        String usernameWithPrefix = "/u:\""+c.getUsername()+"\"";
        String passwordWithPrefix = "/p:\""+c.getPassword()+"\"";
        String targetIpAdressWithPrefix = "/v:"+targetIpAdress;

        processBuilder.command("xfreerdp",usernameWithPrefix,passwordWithPrefix,targetIpAdressWithPrefix,"+auth-only","/cert:ignore");
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        String res = new String(process.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
```

Output is like that although credentials is valid:

[00:53:49:700] [161077:161078] [WARN][com.freerdp.core.nla] - SPNEGO received NTSTATUS: STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE [0xC000006D] from server

[00:53:49:700] [161077:161078] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - nla_recv_pdu:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_LOGON_FAILURE [0x00020014]

[00:53:49:700] [161077:161078] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - rdp_recv_callback: CONNECTION_STATE_NLA - nla_recv_pdu() fail

[00:53:49:700] [161077:161078] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - transport_check_fds: transport->ReceiveCallback() - -1

[00:53:49:700] [161077:161078] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - Authentication only, exit status 1

[00:53:48:174] [161077:161078] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Authentication only. Don't connect to X.

When I run command in terminal, I get normal output which says credentials is valid. Also, when I write code like this:

```
        String usernameWithPrefix = "/u:\""+c.getUsername()+"\"";
        String passwordWithPrefix = "/p:\""+c.getPassword()+"\"";
        String targetIpAdressWithPrefix = "/v:"+targetIpAdress;

        processBuilder.command("/bin/bash","-c","xfreerdp "+usernameWithPrefix+" "+passwordWithPrefix+" "+targetIpAdressWithPrefix+" +auth-only /cert:ignore");
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        String res = new String(process.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
```

I am getting normal output again. I solved my problem with "/bin/bash -c command" but I wonder why first version of my code does not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

bash isn't the OS. When you type e.g.:

```
xfreerdp /u:"foo"
```

bash takes that command and goes to town on it. it replaces `*` with a space separated list of all files, it does variable substitution, and crucially it **removes all quotes** (double and single) as those are signs *to bash* to do certain things (double quotes: Don't consider spaces inside them to separate arguments, single quotes: Same, *and* do not perform certain expansions, such as globs (`*`) inside them).

`ProcessBuilder`/`Runtime.exec` **do not use bash**. And bash is not the OS. They send the provided command and args **directly** to the OS with very little processing. Thus, it literally sends `/u:"foo"` to the xfreerdp process, whereas bash would remove those quotes.

solution: Ditch the quotes. There is no need for them - they serve to tell bash not to split args on spaces within, and with processbuilder *there is no arg splitting at all* - you pass each arg as a separate string already.